# Excel Macro Find Last Row In Column B, Select another cell A1, drag formula from A1 to last row in B

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do an AutoFill in Excel where I can make my macro:

1. Find the last row with data in column B (lets say this is `B40`), and remember.
2. Select `A1`.
3. Drag `A1`'s formula to the row that was found in step 1 (which would be `A40`) so as to perform an autofill the formula.

I am pretty noobish at VBA so would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```
' Get last row with data in column B...
Dim intLastRow As Long
intLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

' Fill column A down to this row... 
Range("A1:A" & intLastRow).FillDown
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even require a [Range.FillDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) or [Range.AutoFill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) method in this case.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 1) = .Cells(1, 1).Formula
End With
```

Just start with the top-left cell and use the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to expand it to the desired dimensions and transfer the formula.